# The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type Fragment (support.v4.app.Fragment)

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I'm trying to get a map working within Fragments, but I get "The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type Karta on the code below. 
I have also tried using getFragmentManager instead of getSupportFragmentManager, but then I get "Cannot cast from Fragment to MapFragment".

Karta.Java:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;

    import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

    public class Karta extends SupportMapFragment{



        public static Karta newInstance() {
            Karta f = new Karta();
            return f;
        }


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.karta, container, false);
    System.out.println("OnCreateView");
            return v;
        }   

        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View v, Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onViewCreated(v, savedInstanceState);
    System.out.println("onViewCreated1");
        final LatLng BUTIKPLATS = new LatLng(57.873873, 11.974995);
    System.out.println("onViewCreated2");   
        GoogleMap karta;
            karta  = ((MapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.karta)).getMap();

            karta.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(BUTIKPLATS).title("Vita Fläckens Blommor"));
            karta.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
            CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(BUTIKPLATS, 17);
            karta.animateCamera(update);

        }
    }
```

karta.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/BGColor"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<fragment
          android:id="@+id/karta"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To literally address your question, replace `MapFragment` with `SupportMapFragment`, so you have:

```
karta  = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.karta)).getMap();
```

However, you have bigger problems.

You have `Karta` extend `SupportMapFragment`. That is fine. But then, you are having it inflate a layout, which is not needed. Moreover, you are having it inflate a layout that contains a `MapFragment`, not a `SupportMapFragment`, and `MapFragment` will not work in your code.

I think if you:

- Delete the layout
- Delete `onCreateView()`
- Change the `karta` line as I suggested at the top of this answer

then I think that you will be OK.

Comment: Hmmm I have probably done something wrong, but: 

I replaced MapFragment with SupportMapFragment, like you said and that got rid of the error. But if I remove the onCreateView, I get error at "GoogleMap karta;" and the line under that one. -See comments in http://pastebin.com/gmFdJgvu. 

If I remove the layout, Where is it defined where the map is shown?

Comment: @Sluggo: Your syntax errors are because you deleted the opening lines of your `onViewCreated()` method. The map is shown wherever you are displaying this `Karta` fragment.

Comment: ..So I should keep the onViewCreated()?   If I do that, I get a crash: "01-16 21:15:36.797: E/AndroidRuntime(1161): java.lang.ClassCastException: nu.sluggo.testapp.foretagsinfo.DetaljFragment cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" (DetaljFragment is the fragment that should be replaced with this mapfragment)

Comment: Replaced onViewCreated() with onCreate. -Worked! It doesn't take the marker and LatLngZoom though.