# GoogleMap settings (addMarker, setMapType & CameraUpdate) not working in SupportMapFragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, supportmapfragment

My map starts as it's supposed to, but the settings for the marker, mapType and zoom never applies in my SupportMapFragment. When I launch the same code in another project, in MainActivity instead, everything works. How do I do to make it work in the SupportMapFragment?

MainActivity (working):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private final LatLng BUTIKPLATS = new LatLng(57.873873, 11.974995);

    private GoogleMap karta;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        karta  = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.karta)).getMap();

        karta.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(BUTIKPLATS).title("Vita Fläckens Blommor"));
        karta.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(BUTIKPLATS, 17);
        karta.animateCamera(update);
    }


}
```

SupportMapFragment (Not working):

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class Karta extends SupportMapFragment{



    public static Karta newInstance() {
        Karta f = new Karta();
        return f;
    }


private GoogleMap karta;
private final LatLng BUTIKPLATS = new LatLng(57.873873, 11.974995);

public void onCreate(View v, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
System.out.println("onViewCreated1");

        karta  = ((SupportMapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.kontaktVisaFragment)).getMap();
System.out.println("Karta initierad (.getMap)");        
        if (karta !=null){
System.out.println("Karta != null");            
            karta.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(BUTIKPLATS).title("Vita Fläckens Blommor"));
            karta.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

            CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(BUTIKPLATS, 17);
            karta.animateCamera(update);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onCreate()` of `SupportMapFragment` is too soon to be trying to manipulate the `GoogleMap`, as it does not exist yet. You need to wait to a later point in time, when the `GoogleMap` object exists, or leave the code where it is in your activity.

`onViewCreated()` from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21169886/115145) should be a better choice than `onCreate()`. However, I had made things too complicated in my answer. Replace:

```
karta  = ((SupportMapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.kontaktVisaFragment)).getMap();
```

with:

```
karta=getMap();
```

Comment: Thanks again! You're an angel! It worked both with and without ((SupportMapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.kontaktVisaFragment)).  I tried to change it to onViewCreated before, but it crashed then. I must have done something wrong that time.